# Does Sublime Text 2 have an auto-complete function?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext

Does Sublime Text 2 have an auto-complete function? And how do I enable it?

Comment: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/auto_complete.html

Answer (score 5):

Sublime Text 2 has autocomplete.

In the beta version (http://www.sublimetext.com/2), you can activate it using control + space.

In the lastest dev version (http://www.sublimetext.com/dev), Sublime Text 2 will automatically activate autocomplete as you type.

Comment: In Sublime Text 2, all you need to do is simply press Tab to autocomplete. See my answer.

Comment: What's the point of downvoting and commenting on a year old, now obsolete thread about an application that has seen major revisions in its autocompletion?

Comment: @BoundinCode can you link to something current? or update your answer to make it current

Answer (score 4):

Here's a plugin which shows auto-completion hints with the available modules/symbols **in real time**
(i.e. the auto-completion automatically pops up when you start typing code) https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel

Comment: SublimeCodeIntel will cause high cpu usage under linux x64

Answer (score 2):

Auto-complete is now available in Beta Build 2165.  It uses Sublime's fuzzy matching algorithm offering you suggestions after typing a few letters. It's toggled on by default but can be turned off by changing the file setting "auto_complete" to false

Answer (score 1):

Press Tab to autocomplete. It doesn't get simpler than this :)

For word completion, all you need to do is type at least one letter of a word and press Tab (This would cycle through the word matches, somewhat like Ctrl+P does in vi, or Esc in TextMate). Pressing Ctrl+Space shows a list of word matches.